# table with different cell height *multirow*

Tags: tables, longtable, multirow

This is my current status. I have tried a lot of things to achieve the layout in the second picture but it simply doesn't work. 
[image: my code]

[image: What i want to achieve]

Here is my code

```
    \begin{longtable}{|p{.37\textwidth}|p{.01\textwidth}|p{.01\textwidth}|p{.01\textwidth}|p{.01\textwidth}|p{.01\textwidth}|p{.01\textwidth}|p{.36\textwidth}|}
    \hline
    \textbf{Conversion}
    &\textbf{\rotatebox{90}{sehr deutlich}}
    &\textbf{\rotatebox{90}{deutlich}} \vspace{0.7em}\raggedright{ausreichend}
    &\textbf{\rotatebox{90}{weitgehend}}
    &\textbf{\rotatebox{90}{gering}}
    &\textbf{\rotatebox{90}{sehr gering}}
    &\textbf{\rotatebox{90}{Aussage nicht möglich}}
    &\centering{Bemerkungen}
\end{longtable}

\vspace{-2em}

\begin{longtable}{|>{\centering\arraybacksclash}p{.95\textwidth}|}
  \hline
  \rowcolor{light-gray}
  \textbf{slten} \\
\end{longtable}
\vspace{-1.1em}

\begin{tabular}{@{}|p{.37\textwidth}|c|c|c|c|c|c|p{.345\textwidth}|}\hline
  \multirow {brachte durchdachte, themenbezogene Beiträge ein.} & 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1 & {Foo mahe fsdaflkdsaflknasdflknsaaflkdsaflknasdflknsaaflkdsaflknasdflknsaaflkdsaflknasdflknsaaflkdsaflknasd aflkdsaflknasdflknsa aflkdsaflknasdflknsa aflkdsaflknasdflknsaflknsaaflkdsaflknasdflknsadlkfnsanf asdnlk nflak} \\\cline{1-7}
   {beobachtete genau.} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \\ \cline{1-7}
     {erklärte Sachinhalte treffend.} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \\ \cline{1-7}
    {stellte Zusammenhänge zwischen Sachinhalten her.} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \\ \cline{1-7}

\end{tabular}
```

I really appreciate every help. I have put red pointers on what I cannot do.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What you want is not very clear. Must the multirow cells be bottom-aligned?

Comment: the bottom line of the first vertice where this phrase "brachte durchdachte, themenbezogene Beiträge ein." shouldnt be at the bottom , what i want to achieve is the second picture. i have putten red pointers where im stucked. excuse my englisch im not a native speaker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
    \usepackage{ragged2e} 
    \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{rotating}
    \usepackage{ltablex, multirow, makecell}
    \renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize\bfseries}
    \settowidth{\rotheadsize}{\theadfont Aussage nicht möglich}
    \renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
    \usepackage{geometry}

    \begin{document}

    \keepXColumns
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X|*{6}{c|}X|}
    \hline
    \centering \textbf{Conversion}
    &\rothead{sehr deutlich}
    & \rothead{deutlich} %
    & \rothead{weitgehend}
    & \rothead{gering}
    & \rothead{sehr gering}
    & \rothead{Aussage nicht möglich}
    &\centering{Bemerkungen} \tabularnewline
    & \multicolumn{6}{c|}{ausreichend} & \\
  \hline
  \rowcolor{lightgray}
  \multicolumn{8}{c}{\bfseries slten} \\
  \hline
  \multirow{1}{=}[1ex]{brachte durchdachte, themenbezogene Beiträge ein.} & 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1 & {Foo mahe fsdaflkdsaflkna sdflknsaaflkdsaf lknasdflkn saaflkds aflknasdflknsa aflkdsaflknas dflknsaaflkdsaflkn asd aflkdsaflknasdflknsa aflkdsa flknasdflknsa aflkdsaflknasdflknsaflknsaaflkdsaflknasdflknsadlkfnsanf asdnlk nflak} \\
  \cline{1-7}
   {beobachtete genau.} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \\ \cline{1-7}
     {erklärte Sachinhalte treffend.} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \\ \cline{1-7}
    {stellte Zusammenhänge zwischen Sachinhalten her.} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \\ \cline{1-7}
    \end{tabularx}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: hi @Bernard thanks , yes as a first step, have u an idea how to solve the second problem the line of the first vertice should  not be there but at a higher level (i mean the second red pointer )

Comment: @GmaSa: If I  understand you correctly, you can delete the `\multirow` command around 'brachte durchdachte, temenbezogene Beiträge ein'  and add `\multirow{6}{=}` to the text in the 'Bemerkungen'  column.

Comment: @Gmasa: Actually I'm not sure of what you call the ‘first vertice’. Do you  mean the first line of `brachte durchdachte, themenbezogene Beiträge ein.` should be centred w.r.t. the row of  `1`s in the following columns?

Comment: with vertice i meant row . @leandriis thanks i have used \multirow{4}{2in} in the last column and that solved my problem . thank you every one :)

Comment: @Gmasa: You didn't answer my second question: must the content of  this cell be vertically centred w.r.t. the following 1s?

Comment: @Bernard yes it must be centerd , thanks for the answer :)

Comment: @Gmasa: I've adjusted the code with the optional argument of `\multirow`.